# File Handling c++ in linux

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

Hi I am trying file handling in ubunto linux. I have a code that runs fine in virtual studio in windows but gives problems in Linux. Following attached is the code and screenshot of error. The code is to read a file check if there is an integer in the file and if any increase it by 1.
code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 ifstream fin;
 ofstream fout;
 char abc[20];
 fin.open("input.txt");
 fout.open("output.txt");
 while (!fin.eof())
 {
     fin.getline(abc, 20);
     for (int j = 0; abc[j] !=0; j++)
     {

         char ab[20];
         int s = abc[j];
         int i = 0;
         bool check = false;

         while ((s >= 48) && (s <= 57))
         {
             
             check = true;
             
             ab[i] = abc[j];
             i++;
             j++;
             s = abc[j];
             
         }
         if (check)
         {
             ab[i] = 0;
             i = 0;
             int a = atoi(ab);
             a++;
             fout << a;
         }
         else
             fout << abc[j];


     }
     fout << endl;
     for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
     {
         abc[k] = 0;
     }
 }
 fin.close();
 fout.close();


}
```

[error given in linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQKrn.jpg)

Comment: `gcc` -> `g++`.

Comment: `gcc` is for compiling C, `g++` is for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` is for compiling C program. You should use `g++` instead to compile C++ program.

Comment: otherwise you can add -lstdc++ to gcc options to compile C++ code

Comment: @SannanYousuf Press the green tick on the left to mark your question as solved.